# Reference request: Every vector subspace of codimension $1$ of a vector space $A$, is the kernel of some nonzero functional $f$.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

I know the following statement is true, but I am looking to find a good reference that proves this quite nicely

> Every vector subspace of codimension $1$ of a vector space $A$, is the kernel of some nonzero functional $f$.

Can anyone please provide me with a nice reference?

Comment: If $U \subset V$ has codimension $1$, it means that $V/U \cong K$ where $K$ is the base field. Now, the functional is simply the projection $V \to V/U$.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace $U$ of $V$ has codimension $1$ if and only if $V/U$ has dimension $1$. In particular, there exists $v\in V$ such that $v\notin U$.

Consider $\{v_\alpha\}$, a basis of $U$; then it is easy to prove that $\{v\}\cup\{v_\alpha\}$ is a basis of $V$. Can you define the requested functional?

Remark. For infinite dimensional spaces this requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Why do you say this requires the axiom of choice? $V \rightarrow V/U \cong K$. I don't see anything complicated in that.